# PhoneGap / Cordova pass appdelegate variable to JS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

**I'm trying to achieve the following:**
Get my cordova based app to open pdf files coming from other apps and use that file to display that pdf. In the end, the objective is to upload it to my server.

**I have achieved the following:**
- App show up in the "open with" menu for pdf files
- App launches and in the appdelegate.m file, I get the path thanks to this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (url){
        NSLog(@"The file contained: %@",url);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Can I use that url if I send it back ? In swift I had a /var/... path not a file://... path !
2. How do I send this url to become a JS variable ?

I know how to do that in swift (started learning it a few days ago) but never worked with objective-c.
If you have a suggestion, I would love a very explicit answer since I have no idea how to use objective-c methods and won't need objective-c in a close future.

***** EDIT *****

In a pure swift project, I have the following in my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
var file_url:NSURL!
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    file_url = url
    return true
}
```

And then declare in the ViewController.swift :

```
func displayLaunchDetails() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    if appDelegate.file_url != nil {
        webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: appDelegate.file_url))
    }

}
```

Later on, in the `viewDidLoad()` function, I call it that way :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "displayLaunchDetails",
        name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil)
```

In this example, I'm loading the PDF file into a webView if a file was passed into my app.

Translating this into objective-c is one thing (I have no idea how to call this in a .m file), sending this variable back to the javascript thanks to cordova is another one... and I'm stuck on both.

Comment: You mentioned that you know what to do in Swift, can you please add this code? It will be easier to understand what you want to achieve, and I can easily "translate" it to objective c

Comment: Just added some code but the swift method did not use or interact with cordova and javascript.
Sending this url back to the JS is what I need this time, which is quite specific !
@RobertoFerraz are you familiar with phonegap (or essentially cordova) ? Thanks for helping !

Comment: OK, I just found a way to send some JS to over to cordova... now my problem would be to send the variable from my AppDelegate.m file to some in the cordova sub-project and to the CDVUIWebViewNavigationDelegate.m file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should call a js function called `doSomething` passing the url as param.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (url){
        NSLog(@"The file contained: %@",url);
        NSString * jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doSomething('%@');",url];
        [self.viewController.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];
    }
    return YES;
}
```